# Captilize every word in ECHO string with PHP

Tags: php, echo, capitalization

Aps if this seems really basic, I'm not a PHP developer.

OK this shows you how to captalize each word in a string
[Capitalise every word of a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704035/capitalise-every-word-of-a-string-in-php)

BUT, how do you incorporate this into multiple strings being echoed?

For example I have

```
<?php echo $prefillTitle, ' ', $prefillFirstname, ' ', $prefillLastname; ?>
```

How would I ensure each parameter echoes with it's first letter as a capital using the ucwords(). Would it be as simple as this?

```
<?php echo ucwords($prefillTitle, ' ',  $prefillFirstname, ' ', $prefillLastname; ?>
```

Comment: Change the comma's in to periods.

Answer (score 3):

#### Capitalizing the first letter of every word

`ucwords` takes one argument and capitalizes the *first* letter of each word:

```
echo ucwords($string);
```

[ucwords reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)

Note that it will not set the case of the *rest* of the letters to lowercase, so if you want to be sure that they are, you can use `strtolower` first as suggested in the comments:

```
echo ucwords(strtolower($string));
```

[strtolower reference](http://php.net/function.strtolower)

#### Capitalizing every letter of every word

If you want to CAPITALIZE THE STRING (which in hindsight I guess you do!), how about using `strtoupper`:

```
echo strtoupper($string);
```

[strtoupper reference](http://php.net/strtoupper)

There are multiple ways to concatenate your string. You can use the `.` operator:

```
$string = $prefillTitle . ' ' . $prefillFirstname . ' ' . $prefillLastname;
```

Or, as I have done above, you can interpolate the variables:

```
$string = "$prefillTitle $prefillFirstname $prefillLastname";
```

Comment: Anyone care to comment?

Comment: It might be a good idea to call `strtolower()` before  using `ucwords()` to avoid inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$str="$prefillTitle,  $prefillFirstname, $prefillLastname";

echo ucwords($str) ?>
```

Comment: Careful using string interpolation - everyone hates it apparently!

Comment: I know, I was just referring to the fact that my very similar answer was immediately downvoted by several people. It seems that some people have a problem with this approach, although they seem to be keeping quiet about it.

Comment: @Mahendra This is the problem of stack overflow... the users down voted the question without leave a comment: "I do this because...". This functionality needed to have some validation before being accepted.

Answer (score -1):

The way you try to concatenate your string is not valid, change the `,` into `.` and try again:

```
<?php echo ucwords($prefillTitle . ' ' . $prefillFirstname . ' ' . $prefillLastname); ?>
```

This should work.

Documentation: http://php.net/ucwords

The function `ucwords` only accepts 1 parameter as a string.