# How to make capital letter of every word in string in php with html content in it

Tags: php, string

I am making a program in which I need to make capital letter of every word in string.

like, my name is khan become My Name Is Khan

we have a php function ucwords for it.

but how to deal with situation like this...

```
<?php
$title="<span style='color:red'>m</span>y name is kh<span style='color:red'>a</span>n";
echo ucwords($title);
?>
```

actual output::

```
   my Name Is Khan
```

expected output::( M and 'a' of khan should be red )

```
  My Name Is Khan
```

Comment: Where's the function? I think that would be relevant here.

Comment: in statement M also be capital char right?

Comment: Yes M shoud be in capital

Comment: first char should be in red color also?

Comment: @ Paresh Gami, Yes M and a of khan should be red

Comment: M and A is fix in any string?

Comment: M an a are not fix it depend upon string fetched from database...

Comment: Well php cant tell when its html tag so instead of capital M you have capital S in `style` because that's the first word. you could do this - `$title="<span style='color:red'> m</span>y name is kh<span style='color:red'>a</span>n";
echo ucwords($title);`  but it would be better if you would separate php and html from each other

Comment: possible duplicate of [Captilize every word in ECHO string with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199222/captilize-every-word-in-echo-string-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$string = 'my Name Is Khan';
$string = ucwords($string); 
echo $string = ucwords(strtolower($string));
```

this code make first character of each letter upper case

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    <?php
      $title = "<span style='color:red'>";
      $title .= strtoupper("m");
      $title .= "</span>y name is kh<span style='color:red'>a</span>n";
      echo ucwords($title);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS can be used to achieve it:

Create class with text-transform property

```
<style>
    .ucword{ text-transform:capitalize; }
</style>
<br/><br/>
<?php
    $title="<p class='ucword'><span style='color:red'>m</span>y name is kh<span style='color:red'>a</span>n</p>";
    echo $title; 
?>
```