# Capitalise portfolio category string in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, capitalize

I'm trying to capitalise the Wordpress portfolio category string of "Corporate identity".

I have tried using this post: [Capitalise every word of a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704035/capitalise-every-word-of-a-string-in-php), but have had no luck.

URL: http://utopia.gerandeklerk.com/

On the home page, hover over the first portfolio item (Steam Africa 2014), you will notice on the hover-state it lists the portfolio categories "Collateral" and "Corporate identity". The client wants wants it to display "Corporate Identity", as it does in the category filter menu above it.

I added the following string - can someone tell me where I went wrong?

```
$portfolio_category[] = ucwords(strtolower($term->slug)); // Capitalise Portfolio Category String
```

### Below is the code from portfolio.php

```
<div class="filter-container">
  <ul data-drop-content class="filter-list">
  <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
  <?php
   $terms = get_terms("portfolio_category");
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='" . "." . strtolower($term->slug) . "'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>";
  };
  ?>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-drop-down class="filter-select"><span>| More filters</span> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/down-arrow.png"></a>
```

```
<?php
$desired_width = 440;
$desired_height = 440;

if(is_tax()) { // is category page
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'portfolio_category' => $term -> slug, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order'=>'ASC' ); 
}
else { // is main portfolio page
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order','order'=>'ASC' ); 
}
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if($loop->have_posts()) {
```

?>

```
    <div class="portfolio-gallery group isotope">
        <?php
         //output the latest projects from the 'my_portfolio' custom post type
         while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>
    <?php
      $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_category' );
      if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        $portfolio_category = array();
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
          $portfolio_category[] = ucwords(strtolower($term->slug)); // Capitalise Portfolio Category String 
        }
        $the_tax = join( " ", $portfolio_category );
      } else {
        $the_tax = "";
      };       
    ?>

            <div class="portfolio-item <?php echo $the_tax; ?> portfolio-item-<?php the_ID(); ?>">      
                <a class="project-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="thumb-container">
            <div class="portfolio-thumb">
              <?php if( get_field('gray_scale_image') ): ?>
                <img src="<?php the_field('gray_scale_image'); ?>" class="grey-scale-image" />
              <?php endif; ?>
              <?php if( get_field('gray_scale_image') ): ?>
                <img src="<?php the_field('colour_image'); ?>" class="colour-image" />
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>                          
                        </div><!-- /.thumb-container -->
                </a><!-- /.project-link -->
      <h3 class="portfolio-category"><?php echo str_replace('-',' ',ucwords(join(", ", explode(" ", $the_tax))) ); ?></h3>
      <h3 class="portfolio-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            </div><!-- /.portfolio-item -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- .portfolio-gallery -->
<?php } // end if ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It goes wrong on this line

```
<h3 class="portfolio-category"><?php echo str_replace('-',' ',ucwords(join(", ", explode(" ", $the_tax))) ); ?></h3>
```

On this line you can try the following function as you mentioned earlier

```
$bar = ucwords(strtolower($bar)); // Hello World!
```

I Didn't tested the code